# Input output error for the already opened file

Tags: python

I'm directing `sys.stderr` to a file and opening that file in write mode.
Only at the end, I'm closing `sys.stderr` and redirecting it to original `sys.__stderr__`

```
sys.__stderr__ = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open(error_file, 'w')

# main code in between 

sys.stderr.close()
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__ # redirect to original stderr
```

However, it gives me the following error.

```
sys.stderr.flush()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

.

Comment: sys.__stderr__ contains the original value of stderr by default. Why do you reassign it ?

Comment: In case it is empty.

Comment: sys.stderr and sys.\_\_stderr__ refer to different objects. You (effectively) destroy sys.\_\_stderr__ The fact that it uses a dunder name should give you a clue to the fact that you shouldn't modify it

Comment: I don't explicitly flush stderr. I thought that code wanted to do that, regarding sys.__stderr__, I guess you do not suggest "sys.__stderr__ = sys.stderr". Right?

Comment: I see thanks for reminding the dunder's meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern introduced by [@CtrlZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77721532/9997212) is the correct way of doing it. However, if you don't want to make a big indent refactoring to include both `with open(...) as stderr` and `with contextlib.redirect_stderr(...)`, you can use a dummy variable without touching `sys.__stderr__`:

```py
stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open(error_file, 'w')

# main code in between 

sys.stderr.close()
sys.stderr = stderr
```

Comment: Thanks @enzo. I already changed in this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect stderr then you could use this pattern:

```
import contextlib
import sys

with open("/tmp/stderr.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as stderr:
    with contextlib.redirect_stderr(stderr):
        sys.stderr.write("Hello world!") # this will be written to the temp file indicated earlier
```

This technique ensures that stderr returns to its original state once the context manager terminates

Comment: The problem is that I have a huge code below.

Comment: @burcak You could always put your "huge code" into a discrete function and call that from within the context